# Reactjs - multiple titles in a single React app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So, I want to make a title for every view or for every Route in my React app, not just that one in the index.html file (React App).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). It allows you to define custom head tags from within your components.

For example, if you want a component to override the title of the page, you could do it like so:

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

// Inside your render:
<Helmet>
    <title>This is a new title!</title>
</Helmet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current `document.title` of your React app using [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). Simply place a `<Helmet />` component in your render method and set its `<meta>` and `<title>` tags as per the documentation:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>
          <title>My App's First Title</title>
        </Helmet>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You could then override the `<title>` you originally set with additional `<Helmet />` instances. Simply include it within a component passed as a prop to a `<Route />`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyPageComponent = (
  <div>
    <Helmet>
      <title>My App's Second Title</title>
    </Helmet>
    <p>Welcome to my page.</p>
  </div>
);

const MyRoute = () => (
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/myPage" component={MyPageComponent} />
    </Switch>
  );
);
```